# How to write Memory intensive thread in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory

I need a test memory usage of my system using ruby program. 
Could anybody suggest me any memory intensive thread in ruby.
Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/ondrejbartas/cpu-memory-stats ...may be it will give you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = ""

(1..400_000_000).each do
  result << "hello world\n" * 100_000
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`File.open('filename' , 'rb')` should do the trick. It will load the entire file into memory, so just make a couple of different sizes to test with. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-open